# After deployment to heroku, website does not work as expected

Tags: heroku, flask

I managed to create a webapp using Flask. As per the requirements of the project, we were not allowed to store the data in a database, but instead use OOP, thus loosing the data once the server is restarted. Now the problem is that when I run the website locally, it works perfectly, BUT when I deployed it to heroku, it started misbehaving. When I register some users, it will sometimes log them in, sometimes it wouldn't. And also when I put in the wrong credentials, it will sometimes show a flash message, sometimes it wouldn't. Let me share the links:

Link to my project on github: https://github.com/HarithJ/Yummy-Recipes/tree/development

Link to my website on heroku: https://yummy-recipes-harith.herokuapp.com

Answer (score 0):

I think you should add your javascript file below JQuery line.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/UI/myJS.js"></script>
```

Comment: The issue is not with my JS file. The issue is with my flask file, I am controlling user registration and login in from their. But the part that really eats me is: the website works perfectly if you clone it via gitub and run it through flask, but it misbehaves in heroku server...

Comment: If you open Chrome developer console. I see an error message like that. `Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined at myJS.js:14` I recently deployed a small flask app to heroku. It was not working properly. I was suspecting that might be a database issue. But then it turned out that it was not working because of a javascript issue.